# I cannot link my SQL Server database with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem, I can not link my SQL Server database with Visual Studio

This images show the problem brief

- http://store1.up-00.com/2015-07/1436893705031.png
- http://store1.up-00.com/2015-07/143689370512.png

Here I cannot find any database

Comment: You need to use `AHMEDIBRAHIM\SQLEXPRESS` as your server/instance name in your connection string (that's what the first pictures shows) or in Visual Studio's Server Explorer

Comment: @marc_s The Same problem still no DB and i Get the same error above  [link] http://store1.up-00.com/2015-07/1436896178861.png [link]

Comment: You used a forward slash (/) and not a backslash (\\)